# PrintDocument draws only the first report and the second is empty

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to make a report from MySQL database but it is just draw it once on PDF document my you just help me to solve my issue of having the second PDF document empty and what is reason of and my app is taking the data of the report from MySQL.

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class frmPrintReceipt

    Private Sub LoadItemstoDatagrid()
        Dim y As Integer
        Try
            sqL = "Select SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity, Description, ItemPrice, (ItemPrice * SUM(Quantity)) as Amount FROM Product as P, TransactionDetails as TD WHERE TD.ProductNo = P.ProductNo AND InvoiceNo ='" & frmPOS.ListViewpay.FocusedItem.Text & "'  GROUP BY TD.ProductNo"
            ConnDB()
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqL, conn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dgw.Rows.Clear()
            Do While dr.Read = True
                dgw.Rows.Add(dr("TotalQuantity"), dr("Description"), dr("ItemPrice"), dr("Amount"))
                dgw.Height += 19
                y += 19
            Loop

            Panel2.Location = New Point(9, 187 + y)
            Panel1.Height += y
            Me.Height += y
            dgw.Height -= 20
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadReceiptInfo()
        Try
            sqL = "SELECT T.InvoiceNo, CONCAT(Lastname,', ', Firstname, ' ', MI, '.') as StaffName, Quantity, Description, ItemPrice, (ItemPRice * Quantity) as ItemAmount, VatAmount, NonVatTotal, TotalAmount, Cash, PChange FROM Product as P, TransactionDetails as TD, Transactions as T, Staff as S, Payment as Pay WHERE P.ProductNo = TD.ProductNo AND TD.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNo AND S.StaffID = T.StaffID AND Pay.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNO AND T.InvoiceNo = '" & frmPOS.ListViewpay.FocusedItem.Text & "' ''"
            ConnDB()
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqL, conn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If dr.Read = True Then
                lblInvoice.Text = dr("InvoiceNo")
                lblEmpName.Text = dr("StaffName")
                lblDate.Text = Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                lblTime.Text = Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
                lblVat.Text = Format(dr("VatAmount"))
                lblSubtotal.Text = Format(dr("NonVatTotal"))
                lblTotal.Text = Format(dr("TotalAmount"))
                lblCash.Text = Format(dr("Cash"))
                lblChange.Text = Format(dr("PChange"))
                LoadItemstoDatagrid()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadItemstoDatagrida()
        Dim y As Integer
        Try
            sqL = "Select SUM(Quantity) as TotalQuantity, Description, ItemPrice, (ItemPrice * SUM(Quantity)) as Amount FROM Product as P, TransactionDetails as TD WHERE TD.ProductNo = P.ProductNo AND InvoiceNo ='" & frmPOS.txtInvoice.Text & "'  GROUP BY TD.ProductNo"
            ConnDB()
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqL, conn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dgw.Rows.Clear()
            Do While dr.Read = True
                dgw.Rows.Add(dr("TotalQuantity"), dr("Description"), dr("ItemPrice"), dr("Amount"))
                dgw.Height += 19
                y += 19
            Loop

            Panel2.Location = New Point(9, 187 + y)
            Panel1.Height += y
            Me.Height += y
            dgw.Height -= 20
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadReceiptInfoa()
        Try
            sqL = "SELECT T.InvoiceNo, CONCAT(Lastname,', ', Firstname, ' ', MI, '.') as StaffName, Quantity, Description, ItemPrice, (ItemPRice * Quantity) as ItemAmount, VatAmount, NonVatTotal, TotalAmount, Cash, PChange FROM Product as P, TransactionDetails as TD, Transactions as T, Staff as S, Payment as Pay WHERE P.ProductNo = TD.ProductNo AND TD.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNo AND S.StaffID = T.StaffID AND Pay.InvoiceNo = T.InvoiceNO AND T.InvoiceNo = '" & frmPOS.txtInvoice.Text & "' ''"
            ConnDB()
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqL, conn)
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

            If dr.Read = True Then
                lblInvoice.Text = dr("InvoiceNo")
                lblEmpName.Text = dr("StaffName")
                lblDate.Text = Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
                lblTime.Text = Date.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
                lblVat.Text = Format(dr("VatAmount"))
                lblSubtotal.Text = Format(dr("NonVatTotal"))
                lblTotal.Text = Format(dr("TotalAmount"))
                lblCash.Text = Format(dr("Cash"))
                lblChange.Text = Format(dr("PChange"))
                LoadItemstoDatagrida()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            cmd.Dispose()
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmPrintReceipt_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            If frmPOS.chack = True Then
                LoadReceiptInfoa()
                PrintDocument1.Print()
            Me.Close()
        End If
        If frmPOS.chack = False Then
            LoadReceiptInfo()
            PrintDocument1.Print()
            Me.Close()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        Dim bm As New Bitmap(Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height)
        Panel1.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Panel1.Width, Me.Panel1.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0)
        Dim aPS As New PageSetupDialog
        aPS.Document = PrintDocument1
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: If `frmPOS` is a checkbox, then it should probably be `frmPOS.Checked`, not `frmPOS.chack`.

Comment: You need to debug your code. There's way too much there for us to trawl through on the off chance that we notice something. If you don't know how to debug, learn now.